# Defining an alias with java @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to imitate the behavior of the Spring XML alias in @Configuration class.

I have an alias in XML that looks like that:

```
<alias name="${com.some.bean}" alias="myBean"/>
```

I have a @Configuration class that looks like that:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
   @Lazy
   @Bean(name = "bean1")
   public MyBean bean1() { return new MyBean(); }

   @Lazy
   @Bean(name = "bean2")
   public MyBean bean2() { return new MyBean(); }
}
```

I want to load dynamically either `bean1` or `bean2` an give the one that's loaded the alias `myBean`. according to the resolution of `com.some.bean` property. It's easy to do with XMLs, yet I can't find the `@Configuation` equivalent.

**Note**: I do not want to use profiles because that's not how my system currently works and changing all the property resolution to use profiles instead of property files is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

An ugly workaround is to define a `@Bean` which receives the property value as a `@Value` and performs the resolution itself

```
@Bean("myBean")
public MyBean myBean(@Value("${com.some.bean}") String value) {
    if (value.equals("bean1"))
        return bean1();
    else if (value.equals("bean2"))
        return bean2();
    else {
        throw new RuntimeException("nope, something went wrong");
    }
}
```

Comment: So, that was my initial solution (only I used booleans to select the bean but that's the same). I was hoping for something a bit cleaner, but guess this doesn't exist :/ Thanks for your answer!